# Simple way to Narrow down types over Left and Right on Either

Tags: scala, either

Suppose you have the following `Either[A1,B2]` instance where `A1` and `B2` are `map`ed to match `Either[A,B]`, where `A` and `B` have a common subtype `S`. Is there a way to easily narrow down the types `A` and `B` to `S`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fold` with the `identity` function on both sides. Here is an example:

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import play.api.libs.json._
import scala.util.control.Exception._

val parsed = catching(classOf[IllegalArgumentException]) either DateTime.parse(str)
val mapped: Either[JsError, JsSuccess[DateTime]] = parsed
  .right.map(JsSuccess(_))
  .left.map(t => JsError(t.getMessage))
val fold: JsResult[DateTime] = mapped.fold(identity, identity)
```

In this case you start with an `Either[Throwable, DateTime]` which is transformed into an `Either[JsError, JsSuccess[DateTime]]`. Both sides have the common subtype `JsResult[DateTime]`.

The types can be inferred completely in this case. After inlining the variables the code can be reduced to this:

```
(catching(classOf[IllegalArgumentException]) either DateTime.parse(str))
  .right.map(JsSuccess(_))
  .left.map(t => JsError(t.getMessage))
  .fold(identity, identity)
```

Comment: You should be able to just do something like `parsed.fold(t => JsError(t.getMessage), JsSuccess(_))`.

Comment: You are right in this case and also in general: it is possible to gather both left and right mapping functions and provide it to `fold`!